# Input a 2D array using foreach loop

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, foreach

I want to convert the following traditional `for` loop to foreach loop:

```
for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
    for(int j=0;j<3;j++)
        arr[i][j]=sc.nextInt();
```

My attempt is:

```
for(int[] innerArr: arr)
    for(int ele: innerArr)
        ele = sc.nextInt();
```

This doesn't work. I thought that since `innerArr` represents a row of the array, and `ele` represents a single element in that row, the above code would work. But I guess only the existing value of that element in `arr[i][j]` is copied into `ele`. Is it even possible to assign a value to that element using a foreach loop?

Comment: No, it's not possible.

Comment: I'm waiting for you to show me how it's possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The inner loop can't be an enhanced for-loop if you want to write to an element. What you can do is:

```
for(int[] innerArr : arr) {
  for(int i = 0; i < innerArr.length; i++) {
    innerArr[i] = scanner.nextInt();
  }
}
```

Have a look at [JLS14.14.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2-300-B). Then you can see what the compiler is doing to an array access.

Comment: So, are you saying the top answer here won't work? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18931332/enhanced-for-loop-for-2d-array-in-java

Comment: EDIT: The answer of your linked question is wrong. You should stick to your first approach or my answer.

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly! Please elaborate on how the code in the top answer of that link would work? I tried it and it didn't! Maybe I screwed up somehow?!

Comment: @SomenathSinha No it won't work, it makes the code compile but it doesn't do what you want, it always updates the same element [i][0]. And in your case it will update [i][what ever comes from scanner]

Comment: @Oleg Precisely my observation -- it didn't work for me as well!

Comment: @SomenathSinha Sorry I've misunderstood your question and thought you've meant your first approach and dropped the provided link.

Comment: @SomenathSinha The code of that answer uses the values of the inner array as indices of the inner array, which makes no sense. `for (int j : i)
    i[j] = 1;` means that for each value in the inner array (which means 0, since all the values of the inner array are initialized to 0), assign 1 to the index of that value (which will perform the assignment `i[0] = 1` multiple times).

Answer (score 6):

No, it's not possible. An enhanced for loop gives you copies of the array elements (or the elements of the `Iterable`) you are iterating over, so assigning values to them doesn't change the original array (or `Iterable`).

Your enhanced for loop attempt is equivalent to:

```
for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    int[] innerArr = arr[i];
    for(int j = 0; j < innerArr.length; j++) {
        int ele = innerArr[j];
        ele = sc.nextInt();
    }
}
```

You should stick with the traditional for loop in this case.